# Declaring a function input parameter as module

Tags: python, python-typing

Say I have a function, where I want to declare an input parameter of type `module`, what should I chose?

Example:

### `collection/module_a.py`

```
def inner_function():
  return 2
```

### `collection/module_b.py`

```
def inner_function():
  return 3
```

### `app.py`

```
from collection import module_a, module_b

def outer_function(parent_module):
    return parent_module.inner_function()

outer_function(module_a)
outer_function(module_b)
```

In the `def outer_function:` I would like to declare a type for the `parent_module` input parameter, preferably something from the typing library. But I struggle finding something that represents a module?

Comment: There's a [`types.ModuleType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.ModuleType).

Comment: There is an [open mypy feature request/issue to match modules via ``Protocol``](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5018).